# How can I access the value of my hidden Gridview column?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, hide, code-behind, column-width

I have an Id column I need to access programmatically, but I don't want it to display in the GridView. I was able to hide it this way, within the Page_Load event of the code-behind:

```
GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

...but I am not able to retrieve the value from the hidden column. I've got a select button because of setting up my GridView with this: *AutoGenerateSelectButton="True"*

...but when I try to access the value, it gives me an empty string:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string movieId = string.Empty;
    GridViewRow grv = GridView1.SelectedRow;
    movieId = grv.Cells[1].Text;
    . . .
```

How can I access that value? I even tried accessing the value at index 0, just in case the "Select" button column is considered to be at index -1, so to speak, as it is not part of the dataset), but that, too, assigns an empty string to movieId! Index 2 does work, but it's not the value I need -- it's the Movie Title.

To be plain, I AM able to hide the "ID" (MovieId) column, between "More" and "Title":

[image]

...but I can't access the hidden MovieId column. Being invisible shouldn't mean that it doesn't exist.

My GridView in the aspx file:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound" OnPreRender="GridView1_PreRender" 
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"      
            AutoGenerateSelectButton="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MovieId" HeaderText="Movie Id" ItemStyle- 
            Width="0%" SortExpression="MovieId" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MovieTitle" HeaderText="MovieTitle" 
            SortExpression="MovieTitle" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="IMDBRating" HeaderText="IMDBRating" 
            SortExpression="IMDBRating" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MPAARating" HeaderText="MPAARating" 
            SortExpression="MPAARating" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="YearReleased" HeaderText="YearReleased" 
            SortExpression="YearReleased" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Minutes" HeaderText="Minutes" 
            SortExpression="Minutes" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

...and in the code-behind (aspx.cs) I have:

```
protected void GridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = "MORE";
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Text = "ID";
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Text = "TITLE";
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[3].Text = "IMDB";
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[4].Text = "MPAA";
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[5].Text = "YEAR";
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[6].Text = "MINUTES";
}
```

...and again, in the Page_Load event I have:

```
GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

...which does cause the ID column to "disappear" visually (and seemingly otherwise).

So the "More" (select button) column is at index 0 in the GridView, and I'm expecting ID to be at index 1 (albeit invisible).

I'm trying to grab it in the SelectedIndexChanged event like so:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string movieId = string.Empty;
    . . .
    GridViewRow grv = GridView1.SelectedRow;
    // Index 0 should be the "MORE" (Select button) column; index 1 the 
         hidden ID (MovieId) column, index 2 the Title (MovieTitle), etc.
    movieId = grv.Cells[0].Text; // movieId is "" after this line; the actual 
        text in that column is "Select"
    movieId = grv.Cells[1].Text; // movieId is "" after this line; the column 
        is invisible
    movieId = grv.Cells[2].Text; // movieId is the value in the [Movie] Title 
        column after this line; visually, this is column index 1, but I'm 
        expecting it to be actually index 2
    . . .
```

Comment: I would step the code, or put some debug prints. Is the selected row returning ANY data for any of the cells? Also, ViewState is enabled for this control, right?

Comment: Yes, I have stepped through it. Col2 gives me the Title. col3 gives me the IMDB Rating. But column1 gives me nothing (emtpy string); same with column0, but I would kind of expect that (as it is kind of a bogus column, housing the "Select" button). So I can grab a couple of items and query the database for the ID value, but it seems a shame to have to jump through that additional hoop when the ID value should be right there...

Comment: Well, its 1 minute of time to try the row databind. But perhaps the PK id column is miss-matched name wise from the sql query. As I stated, am am surprised that setting visible false ever did work - 99% of cases we have to use style else the page does not include nor have such values as part of rendering. I would double check the PK ID column name. I mean, if using data row bind to set visible does not work, then all bets are off. But setting visible=false in most cases means the control is not available - so not a huge surprise. Data row bind occurs later, so persisting of control works.

Comment: The visible part is working fine. It is hiding what I want to hide. The problem is that I'm not able to access the value in that present-but-not-visible column.

Comment: So far, like most asp.net controls, if you set visible = false, then the control is not rendered. So you have to use a later event like row data bind, or you can/could try using style=none. This is a common and standard issue in most cases. I will admit this case seems different, but removing the one line visible and moving to data row bind results in still only one line of code to accomplish this goal. It is time to note the story about leading the horse to water, but it not willing to drink the water?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Hidden field like this:

```
<asp:HiddenField Id="HiddenField1" runat="server"/>
```

then you have to use `GridView1.SelectedRow` property followed by the cell index and the value of the control (i.e. Hidden field) like this:

```
string movieId = ((HiddenField)Gridivew1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].FindControl("HiddenField1")).Value;
```

Comment: No, I'm not using a HiddenField element; I just need to have the Id column present but not visible. Even if I could give it a width of 0 or maybe 1 it'd be okay, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention if you "just" have a datagrid control, and are shoving in say a datatable.

In that case, you don't have the template structure to play with and hide the column.

```
GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

Without the templated fields (boundcolum template), then no columns collection exists after a data bind.

But you CAN intercept each row binding event with this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow | e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
{
    GridViewRow gRow = e.Row;
    gRow.Cells(1).Visible = false;
}
}
```

So note how we catch either the heading row bind event, or a data row. And thus we just set the 2nd colum visible = false.

NOTE: in most cases, when you set a control visible = false, it is NOT sent to the browser. And in THIS CASE this holds true! Normally we have to use

```
Cells(1).Style("Display") = "none"
```

This will THEN hide the colum, but STILL send the data to the browser. However, in this case (and its rare), the colums are STILL avaiable, but are NOT sent/rendered in the browser. In fact this is quite perfect, since it enhances security - you don't actually send the PK value(s) to the browser - this enhances security by quite a bit. However, if you have/introduce browser side JavaScript? Then you better use style, since visible means the PK id values are NEVER sent to the browser and client side code thus can't get/use the PK values (client side with js).

Ok, so now the above will hide the column for you.

and now in your SelectedIndex change event, you find that you can still get/grab the PK value like this:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Debug.Print("row id = " + GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text);
}
```

So much of this answer assumes/depends on if you are just shoving in a datatable, and you don't have any asp:BoundFields in the template, say like this:

```
<Columns>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True"                     
  etc. etc. etc.
</Columns>
```

From your information given, I have assumed you JUST dragged a gridview onto the form, and you fill it with your code from say a data table.

So, given the above? Then you have to intercept each row that "fires" during a GridView1.Databind() as per above, and that will not only hide the column, but surprising is that the cells() are STILL available, and you will find that the PK values are not even sent down to the browser side of things.

Comment: I am able to hide it, please see Update. Sorry for not giving more info from the git-go, as I DO have BoundField values in the GridView. The "GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text" is what I'm doing, but to no avail (literally, it's "movieId = grv.Cells[1].Text;"); theoretically, that should work!

Comment: Move the visible code to the data bound event as I did. As i stated, if  you in near all cases set a control visible = false, then it will NOT be rendered, and thus not available and not part of the page DOM. The outline code I have to hide the 2nd column should still work even with templated columns as you have. Moving to the row data bind event at least means the control gets rendered and part of the final page. So, I don't think you can hide this outside of rowbind, since visible = false before hand will result in the column never becoming part of the final page and render.

Comment: And as noted, I am surprised that using visible even works - but it does in this case. (using style("display") = "none" in 9 out of 10 cases is better. But as noted, in this case, if visbile can/does work, then it all the better since then PK's are not sent to browser. However, I have used .visible with databound (templated columns), and it should work. And yes, 1st col is 0 (your select link btn), and 1 is next. So, just outright setting visible = false seems to remove the column 100%. If you set this in row data bind event, then it hides as opposed to removes it. Only 2 extra line of code.